# Spring Cloud Contract - Is it possible use a binary payload in message body of contract

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

From the spring cloud contract reference documentation, the following messaging based contract is possible

```
def contractDsl = Contract.make {
label 'some_label'
input {
    messageFrom('jms:delete')
    messageBody([
            bookName: 'foo'
    ])
    messageHeaders {
        header('sample', 'header')
    }
    assertThat('bookWasDeleted()')
}
```

Is it possible to use an alternative message body type that is not a json string, for example, a payload that uses a binary serialization mechanism?

If so, would it be possible to use a method from the contract test base class to return this message body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Finchley, at least for Spring Cloud Stream support, we convert the body to bytes from whatever you pass there. If you don't like the defaults, what you can do is to implement your own  `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.MessageVerifier` interface to tell us how to send and receive messages. That should work without any problems for the producer side. There will be issues unfortunately with the consumer side :|

The problem is that currently when you have the input / output case, we try to use the body directly as it is to match your incoming message with what you've defined in the contract via JSON Paths. So the binary protocol here would fail (check the `org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.messaging.stream.StubRunnerStreamMessageSelector` class). Another problem I see is `org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.messaging.stream.StubRunnerStreamTransformer` so the transformer that we use to trigger a message. It assumes that the body is a String JSON and then converts it into bytes.

So the short answer is that it's not currently properly supported. HOWEVER, due to the pluggable nature of Spring Cloud Contract, you can override these behaviours fully. You can basically disable the default stream support via a property `stubrunner.stream.enabled=false`, copy the contents of `org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.messaging.stream` package, modify it to suit your needs and register the beans. I know that it's not the answer that you were hoping for but I've created an issue (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/664) so that we don't forget about this in the future releases.